# Shell history command- function

Tags: c, linux, function, shell, command

Hi I'm trying to implement a shell on linux and I'm suppose to line up the last 10 commands in the shell's history.

I'm using `system("cat ~/.bash_history");`  command but I dont know how to bring up just last 10 commands.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Surely your assignment requires more of you than for your shell to shell out to another shell (system)?

Comment: yes they both have the same result. What should i do if i want to repeat one of the listed commands?

Comment: 'What should I do if I want to repeat one of the listed commands?' You should get the text of the command and run it through your shell again, as if the user had just typed it.  You do have your shell structured so that doing such things is trivial, don't you?

Comment: yes i do. this is the only part i'm struggling with. But what i failed to mention is that, for example the user enters "2" so the second command of the history list should execute.but i cant seem to implement that

Answer (score 1):

Try **tail** command and **-n** is number of last lines,

```
system("tail -n 10 ~/.bash_history");
```